# Where can I find books about how to use Mathematica solving practical problems?

Tags: reference-request

I can use Mathematica solving commman maths problems like Calculus,Linear Algebra and visualize functions.When I want to improve programming level,I find that most tutorials out of practical problems.Where can I find books about how to solve engineering problems or how to solve engineering mathematics problems?

Comment: Did you check the [Wolfram Books page](http://www.wolfram.com/books/topics.html?topic=Engineering)?

Comment: Specifically, you may want to have a look at [these books which are classics](http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/). Unfortunately, they have never been updated beyond version 5.1. I don't know if I can write an answer, though - the question is very broad. One thing Trott writes in one of his books: "*Mathematica* ... ages quickly in the sense that in the timescale $10^{1.\text{small integer}}$, a new version will likely be available."